# Consulta em SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Ao fazer a sequinte query

```
select * FROM conta
```

Ele me trás as colunas, sendo que o `id_fornecedor` vem da tabela `fornecedor`

```
  id | id_fornecedor | conta_status
  1  |      1        |     S
```

Gostaria de trazer além do `id_fornecedor` o nome dele também.

Comment: Em qual tabela o nome dele está ?

Comment: o nome da tabela é fornecedor

Comment: Insira na pergunta a estrutura dela assim como você fez na tabela **conta**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, provavelmente os dados do fornecedor estão em outra tabela, correto?

Você consegue fazer isso trazendo os dados relacionados (no caso o nome do fornecedor) dessa outra tabela.

Vamos imaginar que o nome da outra tabela é **fornecedor**, ok?

```
SELECT c.*, f.nome
  FROM conta c
 INNER JOIN fornecedor f ON f.id_fornecedor = c.id_forncedor
```

Se sua dúvida persistir, retorne com mais detalhes das tabelas (nome da tabela, nomes das colunas, etc...)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ficou assim: 
SELECT c.*, f.razao_social
  FROM conta c
 INNER JOIN fornecedor f ON f.id = c.id_forneced

Comment: Que bom que funcionou amigo!