# Consultar dados em duas tabelas e somar uma das colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas preciso fazer um SELECT nas duas ao mesmo tempo, basicamente funcionará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que o resultado, retorna a coluna `nome` da `Tabela A` e soma da coluna `media` onde os `ids` são iguais. E também os nomes onde não há registro na `Tabela B` são exibidos com o valor 0.

Eu procurei no site algo semelhante e não encontrei, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para obter o resultado esperado você precisa fazer um `JOIN` entre as tabelas. Além disso, precisa usar funções de agregação com `GROUP BY` para conseguir agrupar e somar os valores.

Sua *query* ficaria assim:

```
SELECT a.nome, 
       COALESCE(SUM(b.media), 0) AS media
  FROM tabela_a a
  LEFT JOIN tabela_b b ON b.id_usuario = a.id
 GROUP BY a.nome;
```

Uma observação: no exemplo exposto por você **JOSÉ teve os valores somados**, mas **MARIA teve como resultado a média dos valores**, então ficou meio confuso. Se você deseja calcular a média e não a soma, deverá usar a função `AVG` ao invés de `SUM`.

```
SELECT a.nome, 
       COALESCE(AVG(b.media), 0) AS media
  FROM tabela_a a
  LEFT JOIN tabela_b b ON b.id_usuario = a.id
 GROUP BY a.nome;
```

Um exemplo **AQUI** para execução no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/029a7d/3).

---

### JOIN, INNER ou LEFT?

Como as informações estão distribuídas por **duas tabelas** é preciso relacioná-las através da **ligação existente entre as chaves presentes** nelas (**primárias e estrangeiras**).

Conseguimos isso a partir do uso de `JOIN`. Mas existe um diferença importante entre usar `INNER JOIN` e `LEFT JOIN`.

Com `INNER JOIN` o resultado da *query* é limitado aos registros que atendam **integralmente as condições de ligação nas duas tabelas**, ou seja, para cada registro da tabela A temos que encontrar um ou mais registros correspondentes na tabela B.

Se usássemos `INNER JOIN` no exemplo o resultado da *query* traria **apenas os registros de JOSÉ e MARIA**, pois para **JOÃO e ANA não encontramos registros relacionados** na tabela B.

Já com `LEFT JOIN` o resultado da *query* corresponde ao **total de registros** originados da tabela encontrada no **lado esquerdo da relação**, no nosso caso, a tabela A. Não há a necessidade da existência de registros relacionados na tabela B. Por isso, com o uso do `LEFT JOIN` pudemos trazer todos os nomes no resultado, independente de existir informação na tabela B.

### GROUP BY

Através do `GROUP BY` **agrupamos registros** da *query* e podemos aplicar as **funções de agregação** sobre os campos para efetuar operações como contagem (`COUNT`), cálculo de média (`AVG`), soma (`SUM`), entre outras.

### COALESCE

Como não teremos informações sobre **JOÃO e ANA na tabela B** o **resultado da aplicação de uma função de agregação** para seus registros, seja a média (`AVG`) ou a soma (`SUM`), **será nulo** (`NULL`).

A função `COALESCE` permite que o `NULL` **seja substituído por outro valor**, 0 nos exemplos. Ela avalia todos os parâmetros informados e retorna sempre **o primeiro diferente de nulo**.

- `COALESCE(NULL, 1, 3)` retorna o segundo parâmetro, o valor 1.
- `COALESCE(2, 1)` retorna o primeiro parâmetro, o valor 2.
- `COALESCE(AVG(b.media), 0)` retorna a média, se diferente de `NULL`, senão 0.

Neste caso específico também poderíamos utilizar a função `IFNULL` (que só aceita 2 parâmetros, enquanto `COALESCE` pode avaliar vários parâmetros) com o mesmo resultado do `COALESCE`.

### Documentação

[Documentação MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

[Documentação MySQL GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

[Documentação MySQL COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

[Documentação MySQL IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

### Mais informações e exemplos

[Como exibir dados de uma tabela da chave estrangeira na minha tabela principal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135524/como-exibir-dados-de-uma-tabela-da-chave-estrangeira-na-minha-tabela-principal)

[Consulta de categoria no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134259/consulta-de-categoria-no-mysql)

[Consulta em SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130483/consulta-em-sql-server)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Emerson, seu exemplo funcionou perfeitamente! Vou dar uma lida no material, pois não conhecia `COALESCE()`

Comment: Que bom que funcionou, acabei de adicionar link para execução do exemplo.

Comment: Você poderia usar o [ISNULL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) , também teria o mesmo resultado

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza, no caso do MySQL o similar seria o `IFNULL`, pois `ISNULL` é função de comparação. O `ISNULL` funcionaria no SQLServer. Correto?

Comment: @EmersonJS, verdade, :) isso no no sql server mysql é IFNULL :)